# MS Windows 10: Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url

Tags: node.js, windows, git

I'm trying to install my project dependencies using **npm i** on Windows machine. However I'm landing this error:

```
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:202:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+https://5345345erg345eg34eg:x-oauth-basic@github.com/test/test.git resetting remote C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-test-89f19adf because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! fatal: bad object 1cf23bc52c0a3b1b5dde89949ff9f820522e0367
npm ERR! fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects
```

I did some research and found that this issues is related to the windows not supporting files and directories longer than 260 characters. The workaround I got was to use this command to allow longpath filename:

```
git config core.longpaths true
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone please suggest a workaround and why this is happening?

**Node and NPM versions:**
**Node:** v6.2.0
**NPM:** 3.8.9

Please let me know if there's more details that I need to provide?

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: @MahinKhan couldn't find any solution. Now have swithced to Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your npm. I had this problem before updating to npm 5.